# Styling list with images

Tags: css, styles

I am looking to style a list with images at the top and the bottom of the list. I know that in css3, there is the [border-image](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) property, however I need something that works in older browsers as well.

The list looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li> a </li>
 <li> b </li>
</ul>
```

I need to have an image that comes before all the list items, and another one that comes after all the list items.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
<div id="top-image"></div>
   <ul>
    <li> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
   </ul>
<div id="bottom-image"></div>
```

Are there any better options than this?

Comment: `border-image currently works in Safari and Firefox 3.1 (Alpha)` and it doesn't even seem to work in Firefox... I recommend you to try other approaches with your own image sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to define bottom image in `UL background` &  top image in first `LI`. like this:

```
ul{
 background:url(bottom-image) no-repeat left bottom;
}

li{
 background:url(bottom-image) no-repeat 0 0;
}
li + li{
 background:none;
}
```

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/CY5ck/